# How format date in flask using template

Tags: python, templates, flask

I have a list of dates in datetime format and i d'like formate this.

form example:

```
{% for date in dates %}
    {{date}}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 12):

You can use the python strftime function. It works in Jinja2.

```
{% for date in dates %}

    {{ date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') }}

{% endfor %}
```